# How to get date format from iso8601 datei and time in perl

Tags: perl, iso8601

I am parsing data and getting a date.  I then convert that to iso8601 object.  However I am stuck trying to get just the year month date format.

```
use DateTime::Format::ISO8601;
use POSIX qw(strftime);
my $dt_str = 'Frank_Gibson.20180703T230600.Program_Manager.New_York.doc';
my @perl_time_array = split /\./, $dt_str;
my $dt = DateTime::Format::ISO8601->parse_datetime($perl_time_array[1]);
```

prints `2018-07-03T23:06:00`
How do I get just the date? I have tried to use

```
$dt = strftime('%Y-%m-%d',$dt);
```

But I am getting the following error.

```
Usage: POSIX::strftime(fmt, sec, min, hour, mday, mon, year, wday = -1, yday = -1, isdst = -1) at /home/pi/code/perl/perl_regex_lookahead.pl line 26.
```

Do I just use a regex to get what I am looking for or is there a way to format using using `DateTime::Format::ISO8601` or `strftime`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two subroutines called `strftime()` here and I think that's slightly confusing you.

You are (accidentally?) calling the `strftime()` function from the [`POSIX`](https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module and, as your error message tells you, that subroutine expects very specific arguments (basically the list of values you get back from `localtime()` or `gmtime()`).

But you don't need to do that. Your `$dt` variable is an object of the class `DateTime`. And `DateTime` objects have their own `strftime()` method that you can call on the object.

```
$dt->strftime('%Y-%m-%d'); # 2018-07-03
```

It's also worth mentioning that the `strftime()` method is really only intended for creating strings in more obscure date and time formats. For common formats, the `DateTime` class has other methods that you can use. For example, the date format that you want can be produced using the `ymd()` method.

```
$dt->ymd; # 2018-07-03
```

This all means that you can remove the `use POSIX` line from your code. You won't be using that module at all. Everything you need is in the `DateTime` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can build flexible DateTime parser with **DateTime::Format::Builder**. As example you can see source code from **DateTime::Format::MySQL**.
For example:

```
package MyTimeParser;
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;
use DateTime::Format::Builder
(
    parsers => {
        parse_datetime => [
            {
                # 20180703T230600
                regex => qr/^(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})T(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})$/,
                params => [qw( year month day hour minute second )],
            },
            # here you can describe another format
        ],
    }
);
1;

package main;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dt_str = 'Frank_Gibson.20180703T230600.Program_Manager.New_York.doc';
my @perl_time_array = split /\./, $dt_str;

# 2018-07-03
print MyTimeParser->parse_datetime( $perl_time_array[1] )->ymd('-');

exit;
```

Comment: The OP is not looking for a parser, they want to format their output. And that's all already available in the `DateTime` class.